# SQL: Using single count multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am attempting to use a single count multiple times. What I mean by that is to go through and find how many objects are listed under a specific area. So for example, how many books of a particular series there are. The info is being taken from two different tables. Any tips?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Please show some sample data, and the result you're trying to obtain from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not clear. But if I think I understand what you're asking, you're looking for the `GROUP` clause. For example,

```
SELECT series_name, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY series_name;
```

This will give you the counts of each `series_name`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the help. Not sure how to mark this as the correct answer.

EDIT: Nvm, think I did it.